# How to get LastPass Binary Chrome Extension to work across synced machines

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, synchronization, lastpass

Setup:

- I use Chrome Sync regularly across two machines
- I use LastPass as my password manager (it's already paid for this year so no alternatives suggestions, please)
- The [binary version](https://lastpass.com/misc_download.php?fromwebsite=1) allows you to autofill htauth logins plus a few other features

Problem:

The binary version of the extension won't transfer across Chrome Sync so I have to explicitly install it across both machines. The first time I install it on both machines it works just fine and will auto-fill my htauth logins. However, the first Chrome start-up after doesn't load the binary version and won't log into my htauth logins, and THEN brings up the dialogue to install the binary version.

I have already tried to contact LastPass about this, but they feign ignorance on it working across Chrome sync only saying that it doesn't sync the extension across Chrome sync. This is fine for me since I'll just set it up on both machines, but it seems to be syncing the non-binary version (which isn't installed).

How can I get this to work across machines? Is there a way to have Chrome Sync ignore certain extensions completely?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like LastPass needs to register the binary version with the Chrome Store that way it will sync the correct extension. Chrome can't sync what it doesn't know. :-\

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to do was use the universal installer. The program installed maintains the version of the extension once installed.

Comment: Well that didn't work. Started up my laptop this morning and it's prompting me to install the binary version again. ugg. Sending another admin ticket in.

Comment: It was suggested to me by LastPass support that I not use the extension syncing feature. This actually solves it, but it's dumb so I'm syncing extensions and just copy/pasting when the normal methods don't work.